# Перезагрузка страницы при использовании POST запроса в обработчике события submit при наличии event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, fetch, javascript-events

Изучаю json server И POST запросы. Не могу понять, почему у меня происходит перезагрузка страницы. Данные из формы отправляются нормально.

```js
async function postUser(user) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
}
async function getUsers() {
  return await fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data)
}

function getUsersForm() {
  const form = document.querySelector("form");
  const res = form.querySelectorAll(".res");
  form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const userData = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      userData[key] = value;
      res.forEach(item => {
        item.textContent = "Good"
      })
    });
    postUser(userData);
  })
}
getUsersForm()
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Регистрация пользователя</h2>
  <form id="registrationForm">
    <label for="username">Имя пользователя:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
    <div class="res"></div>

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
    <div class="res"></div>

    <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
    <div class="res"></div>


    <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Предоставь пожалуйста свой html.  И проверь, нет ли на сервере переадресации

Comment: Добавил html код. Как проверить переадресацию не понимаю так как только начинаю изучать отправку и получения данных с сервера

Comment: Ну серверную часть кто писал? На чём она написана? Что она делает? Там надо в коде смотреть есть ли перенаправление куда-либо. Это надо код бэка смотреть

Comment: Ошибка не воспроизводится. Скорее всего проблема на серверной стороне, которая куда-то перенаправляет

Comment: По поводу сервера не знаю.  Просто через команды терминала загрузил json server.  Прописал в терминал npx json-server db.json. Он мне дал localhost куда я и отправляю post запросы и после чего в файле db.json сохраняются все данные формы

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике, что вам приходит в ответ от сервера? и какой код ответа